# Highlight numbers in a PDF using Python

Tags: python, pdf, numbers, highlight, pymupdf

I was able to highlight words in a PDF (using the below code). However, I would also like to highlight any number contained in the same PDF. How would you complement such code?

```
import fitz    

# opening the pdf file  
my_pdf = fitz.open("AR_Finland_2021.pdf")
  
# input text to be highlighted  
my_text = "blood"  
my_text1="aid"  

# iterating through pages for highlighting the input phrase  
for n_page in my_pdf:  
    matchWords = n_page.search_for(my_text) + n_page.search_for(my_text1)      
    for word in matchWords:  
        my_highlight = n_page.add_highlight_annot(word)  
        my_highlight.update()     

# saving the pdf file as highlighted.pdf  
my_pdf.save("highlighted_text.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well what you would like then this should help you:

```py
import fitz    

# opening the pdf file  
my_pdf = fitz.open("AR_Finland_2021.pdf")
  
# input text to be highlighted  
my_text = "blood"  
my_text1="aid"

for i in range(0, 10):
    # iterating through pages for highlighting the input phrase
    for n_page in my_pdf:
        matchWords = n_page.search_for(str(i)) + n_page.search_for(my_text) + n_page.search_for(my_text1)
        # print(matchWords)
        for word in matchWords:
            my_highlight = n_page.add_highlight_annot(word)
            my_highlight.update()

        # saving the pdf file as highlighted.pdf
    my_pdf.save("highlighted_text.pdf")
```

The logic used is quite simple: I put it inside a loop so that it would search for each iteration adding to the strings you defined earlier